# (Allauth) Resending verification redirects to another page

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

In a custom template for a profile page, I have this form to resend a verification email:

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load account %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<p>Username: {{user.username}}</p>
<p>Email: {{user.email}} {% if emailadress.verified %}(Verified){% endif %} (Unverified)</p>
<form action="/accounts/email/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input style="display:none" type="text" name="email" value="{{user.email}}" readonly>
    <button class="btn-auth" type="submit" name="action_send">Resend Verification</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This form is submitted from a view located at `/accounts/profile/`, but when submitted, it redirects the user to `/accounts/email/`. I looked through the source code for allauth, but I couldn't wrap my head around how the redirect URL is determined. I tried adding a `next` value in the form, but that didn't do anything. Is there any way to specify the URL to redirect to after resending the verification or should I just move the `/accounts/profile/` template to `/accounts/email/`?

Comment: You have to use AJAX request, to stay on the same page. Do  you have jQuery in your webapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** [**`EmailView`**](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/353386216b79f16709e97bb487c0bbbba2bc0c71/allauth/account/views.py#L409#L409) ([django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/353386216b79f16709e97bb487c0bbbba2bc0c71/allauth/account/views.py#L409#L409)) is also support AJAX request.

So you can simple make an AJAX request with jQuery:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="{% url 'account_email' %}" method="post" name="resendVerification">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <input style="display:none" type="text" name="email" value="{{user.email}}" readonly>
        <button class="btn-auth" type="submit" name="action_send">Resend Verification</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form[name="resendVerification"]').submit(function(e) {
    // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(), // serialize data
        success: function(data) {
            // show response from django allauth
            alert("We have sent an e-mail to you for verification to " + data.data[0].email);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

**2.** Or you can also write a [**simple view**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view) to resend the email verification that redirects your to desired url - `redirect("/accounts/profile/")`:

**views.py**:

```
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter

from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def resend_verfication(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        try:
            email_address = EmailAddress.objects.get(
                user=request.user,
                email=email,
            )
            get_adapter(request).add_message(
                request,
                messages.INFO,
                "account/messages/" "email_confirmation_sent.txt",
                {"email": email},
            )
            email_address.send_confirmation(request)
        except EmailAddress.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    # redirect("named_url") or even better use here named url
    return redirect("/accounts/profile/")
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('profile/resend-verfication/', login_required(views.resend_verfication), name="myapp_resend_verfication"),
    ...
]
```

And then in your form as action use `{% url 'myapp_resend_verfication' %}`:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="{% url 'myapp_resend_verfication' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input style="display:none" type="text" name="email" value="{{user.email}}" readonly>
        <button class="btn-auth" type="submit" name="action_send">Resend Verification</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I imported the premade `send_email_confirmation` function from `allauth.account.utils` and decided to create my own view that redirects back to the profile page.

Comment: what about adding emails? How can we make it an AJAX call?

Comment: @YousufM.N, you can use AJAX example in my answer, but change the button name > `<button name="action_add" type="submit">{% trans "Add E-mail" %}</button>` and of course email input must be readable.